# Why do webdriverIO functions are not working in wdio-v7?

Tags: webdriver, webdriver-io, wdio-v6

I have just started a new project using `wdio-v7`, but none of the `webdriverIO` functions (e.g.: `.click()`, `.waitForDisplayed()`) are working anymore and I receive

> ```
> "TypeError: element.click is not a function"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this happens when I forget to include the dollar sign in the page file. Make sure it looks like this:

```
get element() {
    return $('someId');
}
```